# How do i force \pagebreak on everything in LaTeX

Tags: macros, spacing, page-breaking, programming

I would like to learn how to force a page break on everything that goes over the page. Suppose I have a document that involves multiple images, paragraphs, figures connected to paragraphs and lists. As soon as say a list/paragraph goes over two pages, I would like to automatically force a page break (without having to manually add page break).

I have the following MWE that I am currently working on.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-5]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}]

\item
This is a dummy text. It belong to part 1. This should be forced to start on a new page. \\~\\\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}\qquad  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=0.85cm,itemsep=2ex] \item BLAH BLAH BLAH  \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \end{enumerate}\vskip 9mm

\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[1-4]


\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}]

\item
This item should also start on a new page but the last paragraph should also start a new page. \\~\\ \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-golden}\qquad \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=0.85cm,itemsep=2ex] \item BLAH BLAH BLAH  \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \end{enumerate}\vskip 9mm

\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

To clairfy:

[image: Item 1 should start on a new page]

[image: Item 1 should also start on a new page, however because of previous new page, some of the above paragraph might need to start on a new page.]

[image: The last paragraph should start on a new line.]

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Force a page break *where*?

Comment: `\\~\\ ` ??? why not have a paragraph break there, similarly `\qquad \begin{enumerate}[`  the space there will either do nothing or generate a spurious blank line depending on teh length of the preceding text.

Comment: You could prevent line breaks mid-paragraph but that would require you to mark paragraphs with paragraph breaks not `\\~\\`

Comment: When you compile the MWE, you will notice that a 2 lists go over the page and a paragraph.

Comment: lists in general may be many pages long, how do you want latex to know that the outer `\item` start a new page, but the inner A B C items do not? By far the simplest would be if you put `\newpage` before the items where you wanted a page break.

Comment: Similarly paragraphs can be more than a page long do you want to absolutely prevent  page breaks mid paragraph then handle any page overflow by hand?

Comment: I just want to tell latex to treat a block of text/lists etc as an unbreakable block.

Comment: Put the list items in a minipage and set `\interlinepenalty to 10000` so paragraphs don't break, and use `\raggedbottom`

Comment: Is there a way to generalize the process rather than target each one separately?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. `\interlinepenalty` is global and adding `\begin{minipage}` to stop items breaking is no more "targetted" than adding `\item` to mark it as an item. You could define a local command to reduce the markup if you wished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\interlinepenalty=10000
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-5]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}]

\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
This is a dummy text. It belong to part 1. This should be forced to start on a new page.

%NO!!!!! \\~\\
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\end{flushleft}

%????\qquad  

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=0.85cm,itemsep=2ex] \item BLAH BLAH BLAH  \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \end{enumerate}

% not really latex, vspace or better specify the spacing for the list above
% \vskip 9mm
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[1-4]


\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}]

\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
This item should also start on a new page but the last paragraph should also start a new page.4

% No!! \\~\\ 
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-golden}  
\end{flushleft}

%??????\qquad

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=0.85cm,itemsep=2ex] \item BLAH BLAH BLAH  \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \item BLAH BLAH BLAH \end{enumerate}

% as above\vskip 9mm
\end{minipage}


\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If a paragraph or list is longer than a page the page will overflow and require a manual page break to be forced, I assume that is acceptable here.

Comment: That is the end result I would like, but is there a way of achieving that without having to manually add mini page to where a page break might be needed.

Comment: Ideally, I would like latex to pick up that if something goes over the page, it will force it down to a new page.

Comment: @AlanJones adding `minipage` is no more manual than adding `\item`.  LaTex will typically have shipped out the page, written that part of the PDF and reclaimed all the memory for that part of the document _before_ it reaches the end of the item so there is no way that it can back up when it gets to the end of the list and redo those pages.  You can define `\zzitem` to be `\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}`  then you are just talking about using `\zzitem` rather than `\item` as the list markup, it is no more or less manual.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for your time I appreciate it. (I'm still learning how to play around with its latex capabilities)

Comment: @AlanJones TeX's line breaking doing least cost over the whole paragraph is still state of the art 40 years later, but its page break algorithm is aggressively greedy, in 1980 you couldn't afford to have multiple pages in memory so the whole design aims to ship out a page and get the memory back asap. In most documents actually that isn't so bad as there are limited number of places to break, but if you want to change the rules as here you need to give tex a hint in advance, it really can't back up.

Answer (score 0):

What are the units that stay together? It is not every item or every paragraph, and you don't have sections. Much less "everything".

Once you define the places, put `\filbreak` there.

(That's not like `\pagebreak`, as you asked, but rather like `\newpage`, which is probably what you want.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "once you define the places".  I want to what ever that is going over the page to start on a newpage.

Comment: You say "everything", "something", and "whatever" which don't define the units that must not straddle a page break. Your example says you mean something bigger than an item, but less than the whole text. There is nothing in the document to demarcate such units. I'm suggesting you put `\filbreak` between the units to define them and LaTeX will insert (like) a `\newpage` whenever one of the units would not fit on the current page.